# C#.net Adding usercontrol to panel is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, performance, user-controls

I'm writing a simple email client and I have a usercontrol with 2 labels and 2 panels and 1 picturebox. but creating and adding these usercontrols to a flowlayoutpanel is very slow. for example creating and adding 20 of these usercontrols to panel takes about 10 seconds! I need to make this process a lot faster. any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
    MessagesListPanel.SuspendLayout();

MessagesListPanel.Controls.Clear();

foreach (ImapX.Message message in MessagesLibrary.GetMessageList())
{
    EmailListItem NewEmail = new EmailListItem(MessagesListPanel,
        message.UId,
        !message.Seen,
        message.Attachments.Count() > 0,
        message.From.DisplayName == null ? message.From.Address : message.From.DisplayName,
        message.Subject == null ? "(No Subject)" : message.Subject,
        message.UId == LastSelectedID);

    NewEmail.Click += EmailItemClick;
    NewEmail.FromLabel.Click += EmailItemClick;
    NewEmail.SubjectLabel.Click += EmailItemClick;
    NewEmail.AttachmentIcon.Click += EmailItemClick;

    MessagesListPanel.Controls.Add(NewEmail);
}

MessagesListPanel.ResumeLayout();
```

Constructor of EmailListItem:

```
public EmailListItem(FlowLayoutPanel MPanel, long uid, bool IsUnread, bool HasAttachments, string From, string Subject, bool Selected)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MessagesPanel = MPanel;
        UID = uid;

        if (IsUnread)
        {
            FromLabel.Font = new Font(FromLabel.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            SubjectLabel.Font = new Font(SubjectLabel.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        }

        if (HasAttachments)
            AttachmentIcon.Show();

        FromLabel.Text = From;
        SubjectLabel.Text = Subject;

        if (Selected)
            SelectMessage();
    }

public void SelectMessage()
    {
        Selected = true;

        this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(85, 85, 88);
    }

    public void UnSelectMessage()
    {
        Selected = false;

        this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(65, 65, 68);
    }
```

Comment: Did you check what is taking the majority of the time exactly? Constructing the object? Adding it? The final layout?

Comment: Well it takes about 700ms to construct. adding to panel takes less than 60ms. and the constructor of user-control is not a heavy function (changing label text and showing a picturebox)

Comment: Well if the constructor takes 700ms there is something heavy in there. Could you show some details what happens in there? Are the fields in the `message` object anything but simple properties? Any heavy operations in there?

Comment: as I said nothing special in the constructor.

Comment: There's a very nasty bug in your code, MessagesListPanel.Controls.Clear() does not do what you think it does.  Your program will have thousands of controls after a while.  Yeah, you notice that.  Disposing removed controls is not optional.

Comment: @HansPassant That is right, but given the question I was under the impression that the issue was present right from the start of the application.

Comment: it is from the start... disposing has no effect in this.

Comment: @HansPassant overshot a little with the flag. I do not think that there is a way to remove a duplicated flag anymore. So I think you need to ask the question again.

Comment: Run it through a profiler...you'll quickly see what is eating up the time.

Comment: From what I can see I do not think that it can be anything but what is inside `InitializeComponent()`. Is anything in the generated code that looks strange?

Comment: How long does the GetMessageList method take?